# swift UIsearchbar doesnt show the corresponding image

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

i am trying to make this searchbar show the image that belongs to the title in a tableview. The thing is that it is always showing the first image in the array when searching. how do i get the index for the corresponding image?

```
let tableData = ["One","Two","Three"]
let imageArray = ["indianFood.jpg", "thaiFood.jpg", "chineseFood.jpg"]
var filteredTableData = [String]()


var resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    resultSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    resultSearchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    resultSearchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    resultSearchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    tableView.tableHeaderView = resultSearchController.searchBar

}




override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {


    if (self.resultSearchController.active) {
        return self.filteredTableData.count
    }
    else {
        return self.tableData.count
    }

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) 

    // 3
    if (self.resultSearchController.active) {


        cell.textLabel?.text = filteredTableData[indexPath.section]

    }
    else {

        let image = UIImage(named: imageArray[indexPath.section])
        cell.imageView?.image = image

        cell.textLabel?.text = tableData[indexPath.section]

    }

    return cell


}


func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController)
{
    filteredTableData.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

    let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)
    let array = (tableData as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
    filteredTableData = array as! [String]

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```